# how to deploy angular universal to production

Tags: angular, iis, angular6, angular-universal

so my universal app is up and running on my IIS server
but...

using only localhist:4000

doing so by :

```
npm run build:ssr
npm run serve:ssr
```

any idea how can i work with a real domain ?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Since universal server runs on the top of nodejs, make it alive always using pm2.

After this use the following link to reverse proxy to nodejs app.

http://www.gitshah.com/2013/06/how-to-use-iis7-as-front-end-to-java.html